# Wicket ModalWindow - fixed vertical (start) position

Tags: position, wicket, modal-window

I'm using a wicket application inside an Iframe. This causes a problem in the Internet Explorer. The ModalWindow opens not at the middle of the screen (of the current viewport). It opens at the bottom of the screen and nearly outside of it. I only want it to open some pixels under the start of the Iframe.

It works at Firefox and Chrome and opens correct, but not at the IE.
Only the first appearance must be fixed because the next position will be read out of the cookie anyway.

So are there any solutions for it?

How can I set a fixed vertical position at the beginning (first view of the modal)?

I read the blogpost "Repositioning a ModalWindow in Wicket" by steveswinsburg. But that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is answered in

[Wicket ModalWindow position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28811547/wicket-modalwindow-position)

I used this to give my modal window a new position.